# Referencing $scope in Angular

Tags: angularjs

if I have this function:

```
$scope.updateData = function() {
    chartService.updateChartData($scope);
};
```

What is the correct way to reference $scope on the 2nd line? I imagine, ironically, `$scope` is NOT in scope there?

Comment: $scope is available to use in any of nested function.

Comment: what you'll do with scope in service ?? may be there are many alternate ways that you don't need to pass scope

Comment: yeah, you shouldn't pass scope to a service

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? is it to pass data between controllers via a service/factory?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your replies. In light of the comments suggesting I should be doing this in a different way, I have put a new message up at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164186/better-way-to-reference-scope-in-angularjs dedicated to this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You Should pass whatever you need from `$scope` as parameters in service method.

```
$scope.chart = some chart object

$scope.updateData = function() {
    chartService.updateChartData($scope.chart);
};
```