# Better way to reference $scope in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is how I have my JS set up:

Basically I have a page, and on that page there is a chart. I want to have a loading spinner show while the chart data is loading.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .service('chartService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var svc = {};
    svc.updateChartData = function($scope) {
      $scope.loading = true;
      $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://example.com/getjson'})
        .success(function(response) {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(JSON.parse(response));
          var options = {
            ...
        };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
      $scope.loading = false;
    });
  }

  return svc;
}])

.controller('PageController', ['$scope', '$http', 'chartService', function($scope, $http, chartService) {
  $scope.loading = true;
  // When select option changes
  $scope.updateData = function() {
    chartService.updateChartData($scope);
  };
}])

.controller('ChartController', ['$scope', '$http', 'chartService', function($scope, $http, chartService) {
  // On load
  chartService.updateChartData($scope);
}]);
```

I am using `ng-hide="loading"` and `ng-show="loading" to make sure the spinner and the chart show at the correct times.

However, I've noticed that the call below `// On load` - doesn't actually turn the `loading` to false. Another message on SO suggested there is a better way to achieve this than by passing `$scope` around so any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't pass the scope to your service, a service is meant to be stateless. Just use the `$http` callbacks to set your loading to false

Comment: Aggreed with others keep using callbacks

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good practice to pass your scope object to a service, a service is meant to be stateless. Instead utilize the callbacks of the `$http`:

```
chartService.updateChartData().finally(function(){
    $scope.loading = false;
});
```

And, as Grundy mentioned below, return your `$http` from your service to enable callbacks:

```
svc.updateChartData = function($scope) {
    return $http({ //.. the options });
}
```

I see some more bad practices though. You shouldn't add the data to your DOM from your service, instead utilize also for this the callbacks:

```
svc.updateChartData = function($scope) {
    return $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://example.com/getjson'});
}
```

controller:

```
// When select option changes
$scope.updateData = function() {
    chartService.updateChartData().then(function(data) {
        // success
        // do something with the return data from the http call
    }, function (error) {
        // error
        // handle error
    }).finally (function() {
        // always
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
};
```

For your google chart it would make most sense to create a directive.

Comment: and not forget change `svc.updateChartData` to return `$http` result :-) otherwise you get error, because now this function return nothing

Comment: Given I use `chartService.updateChartData()` twice - once in each controller - how can I reduce code repetition? I shouldn't be doing the whole then/finally thing twice?

Comment: You could store it in a variable in your service, and get the data from there if it already exists

Comment: @b85411 The whole "then/finally thing" is angular's promise system. It is extremely powerful and is at the core of angular itself. Returning the `$http` call returns a promise so it can be resolved when the ajax call returns so yes it is needed, even if you cache it or not. I do not mean to be rude but your comment sounds like you have little knowledge on the subject, this may help http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/deferred-and-promise.html and this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

first,you have two controllers,I'm assuming they are nested relations.
PageController include ChartController.
 you want to change the value of the parent controller in the child controller.
You must use a reference type rather than a value type.

```
$scope.loading =true;
```

change to

```
$scope.loading ={status:true};
```

and if you want to set false,Should be

```
$scope.loading.status =false;
```

NOT

```
 $scope.loading ={status:false};
```

second, you can pass a callback function to service.
like this

```
    svc.updateChartData = function(callback) {
        ....
       .success(){
            callback();
       }
    }
```

controller code change to

```
 .controller('ChartController', ['$scope', '$http', 'chartService', 

function($scope, $http, chartService) {

                // On load
                chartService.updateChartData(function(){
                $scope.loading =true;
                 });

 }]);
```